# ¿Cómo graficar una función digitada por el usuario en spider python?

Tags: python, funciones, spyder

Cuando ingreso una *X* en la función, no me la reconoce el porgrama y esto hace que no me corra, ¿Cómo hago para hacer graficar cualquier función que sea digitado por el usuario?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot

funcion = input("escriba una funcion ")

def f1(x):
    return  funcion

#Valores del eje x que toma el grafico
x = range(-10, 15)

#Graficar la funcion
pyplot.plot(x, [f1(i) for i in x])

#establecer el color de los ejes
pyplot.axhline(0, 
color="red")
pyplot.axvline(0, 
color="Black")

#Limitar los valores de los ejes
pyplot.xlim(-10, 10)
pyplot.ylim(-10, 10)

#guardar grafico como Imagen PNG

pyplot.savefig("output.png")

#mostrarlo.
pyplot.show()
```

Comment: Lo que estás haciendo en `f1` no es correcto. Primero, debes crearte un parseador de texto, que sea capaz de identificar las funciones y transformarla en números y operadores. Y luego otra función que evalue el texto parseado (es decir la función pasada por el usuario) ¡Esa es la clave de este ejercicio!

Comment: Podrías decirme cuales es el parceador y la otra función para que evalúa el texto parseado por favor?

Answer (score 0):

La función `eval` recibe una cadena conteniendo código fuente y lo ejecuta en el entorno actual. Es como si el código en cuestión estuviera directamente escrito el el programa maestro.

Ejemplo:

```
x=5
eval("x**2 + 3")
Out[58]: 28
```

Para que tu programa funcione, sólo necesitas agregar un `eval` en la definición de `f1`

```
def f1(x):
    return  eval(funcion)
```

Ojo: si quieres poder calcular **cualquier** función, tienes que agregar los `import` en el programa maestro. Para las funciones típicas, puedes agregar un `import math`.

Demo:

Ejecutando el programa con esta entrada

```
escriba una funcion: x + math.cos(x)
```

obtenemos este gráfico:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]